# javascript, strange function arrangement, don't understand

Tags: javascript

See the below javascript. When functions are arrangment this way, how is it that they are able to run without being called specifically. What I mean is that the function below runs without being called and I don't understand how.

```
(j, function() {
alert(1);
})
```

it is eval'd like this:

```
eval(s)(j, function() { catch (_) { } }
```

Comment: That shouldn't run the function. Can you show more context?

Comment: That does **not** run the function, sample: http://jsfiddle.net/PeAmw/

Comment: Its part of a larger part of code where I don't know what J is. Is there a J that can initialise this function somehow?

Comment: No. The presence of `j` there cannot invoke the function.

Comment: So would there need to be an eval(j) somewhere? Does J take on the name of the function for calling purposes?

Comment: Maybe you could cite your source, where did you see this?

Comment: you are surely missing a $ or _ in front

Comment: No. The comma operator just returns the right hand side.

Comment: @OBV: how about providing more code around and stopping wasting your and our time?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a `()` at the end? That would explain it.

Comment: eval(s)(j, function() { catch (_) { } }

Comment: OMG, that's terrible. seriously

Comment: It gets passed as an argument to whatever is returned by evaluating `s`. To tell how it gets called, we'd have to see the value of `s`.

Comment: @mplungjan — No, we don't. `$('onload', function () { })` isn't something jQuery does anything useful with.

Comment: I meant `var s = "$",j="load";` http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/HXZVa/
It is late here. Bedtime for me

Comment: How many more ways can they overload the `$` function?…

Comment: What would be an S and a J to just run the function without jQ? Maybe I can plug those variable values in and can check that way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like those are the arguments to a function call, ie

```
foo(j, function() {
   alert(1);
})
```

That will pass the current value of `j` as the first argument, and the function listed there as the second argument.

That said, in order for that function—the one that alerts 1—to be called, `foo` would have to manually call it.  Something along the lines of

```
function foo(j, f){
    f();
}
```

---

EDIT

So, per your question edit, it looks like what's above is more of less correct, except instead of referencing the function directly, you're fetching it from an eval statement.

Something like this:

```
function foo(j, f){
     f();
}
var s = "foo";
var j = 0;
eval(s)(j, function() {
    alert(1);
})
```

Here's a working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/arackaf/TpDHF/)

Comment: @mplungjan: I upvoted. Following that it is 1 of 7 (15%) I assume it was taxes.

Comment: @mplungjan - while a comment is always appreciated when there's a problem with an answer, whoever downvoted has no obligation to do so.

Comment: Yes they do. Unless there is a comment already that the downvoter can agree with, it is friggin mandatory to leave a message or stop using SO

Comment: I didn't vote on this, but the downvoter might have considered this a guess. There's a chance it's a function call, but if there's missing code it could also be an IIFE.

Comment: @AdamRackis I also upvoted, but you should mention that `foo` has to call the second parameter. Just passing it doesn't run it, of course.

Comment: @ComFreek: "has to call the second parameter" --- it's a second level guess :-)

Comment: @zerkms Waiting for more taxes to come :) You're in my profile, now. I hope you don't mind :D

Comment: @mplungjan Commenting while downvoting is not required at all, the see discussion at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: I know it is not REQUIRED, just plain good manners! - I voted for the first couple of suggestions in your link